# Qt QQmlApplicationEngine refuse to display qml code

Tags: qt, qml

I have this pro file

```
QT += qml quick widgets
TARGET = sPassKeeper
include(src/src.pri)
include(qml/qml.pri)
RESOURCES += \
    resources.qrc
```

in src pri and qml pri only single lines
qml.pri

```
OTHER_FILES += \
    qml/main.qml
```

src.pri

```
SOURCES += \
    src/main.cpp
```

In main.cpp got this code

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine(QUrl("qrc:/new/prefix1/qml/main.qml"));
    qDebug() << "Ok engine created";
//    Q_UNUSED(engine)
    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

ApplicationWindow{
    title: "sPassKeeper"
    Button{
        text: "Hello"
    }
}
```

As a result got this output

> QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment. Ok
>   engine created

Nothing displayed and process is not completed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing this:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
```

Qt Creator's new project wizard (`New File or Project... > Qt Quick Application`) has a step where you choose the component set (`Select Qt Quick Component Set`). If you choose Qt Quick Controls (which are required in order to use `ApplicationWindow`), Creator generates the correct code for you:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }

    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer a little prettier

Answer (score 2):

You need to create QQuickWindow from object created by engine. This is a [peace of code](https://github.com/Kakadu/lablqt/blob/master/lablqml/startup_stubs.c#L131) from my project about it:

```
  engine.load(QUrl(QString(String_val(_qmlpath))));
  QList<QObject*> xs = engine.rootObjects();
  if (xs.count() == 0) {
    Q_ASSERT_X(false, "Creating C++ runtime", "Your QML file seems buggy");
  }
  QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(xs.at(0) );
  window->showMaximized();
  app.exec();
```

Comment: Sorry, but I have to disagree with this being a great answer. It may solve the problem, but the correct solution is much simpler and less hacky. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display root object (`Window` or `ApplicationWindow`) in foolscreen mode, then you may do the following:

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    visibility: Window.FullScreen
}
```

Possible useful values for `visibility` are: `Window.FullScreen` and `Window.Windowed`.