# Rectangle element is not displayed

Tags: qt, qml

I want to make a Qt Quick Application project in Qt 5.2.1(msvc2012) using `Rectangle` element.
Here is my `main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: "red"
}
```

When I run this project, building is never finished and I don't see any application window.
Application output stays at:

> QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.

Here is my `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Here is my pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick widgets

SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)
```

Here is my deployment.pri:

```
android-no-sdk {
    target.path = /data/user/qt
    export(target.path)
    INSTALLS += target
} else:android {
    x86 {
        target.path = /libs/x86
    } else: armeabi-v7a {
        target.path = /libs/armeabi-v7a
    } else {
        target.path = /libs/armeabi
    }
    export(target.path)
    INSTALLS += target
} else:unix {
    isEmpty(target.path) {
        qnx {
            target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
        } else {
            target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
        }
        export(target.path)
    }
    INSTALLS += target
}

export(INSTALLS)
```

Here is Compile Output:

> 22:21:25: Running steps for project 521msvc20123... 22:21:25:
>   Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step. 22:21:25: Starting:
>   "C:\qtcreator-3.1.0\bin\jom.exe"      C:\qtcreator-3.1.0\bin\jom.exe -f
>   Makefile.Debug    C:\QtDva\5.2.1\msvc2012\bin\rcc.exe -name qml
>   ..\521msvc20123\qml.qrc -o debug\qrc_qml.cpp  cl -c -nologo -Zm200
>   -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc /Fddebug\521msvc20123.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_QML_DEBUG
>   -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"........\QtDva\5.2.1\msvc2012\include" -I"........\QtDva\5.2.1\msvc2012\include\QtQuick" -I"........\QtDva\5.2.1\msvc2012\include\QtQml" -I"........\QtDva\5.2.1\msvc2012\include\QtWidgets" -I"........\QtDva\5.2.1\msvc2012\include\QtNetwork" -I"........\QtDva\5.2.1\msvc2012\include\QtGui" -I"........\QtDva\5.2.1\msvc2012\include\QtANGLE" -I"........\QtDva\5.2.1\msvc2012\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"........\QtDva\5.2.1\msvc2012\mkspecs\win32-msvc2012" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Temp\qrc_qml.obj.7128.454.jom
>   qrc_qml.cpp   echo 1 /* CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID */ 24 /*
>   RT_MANIFEST */
>   "debug\521msvc20123.exe.embed.manifest">debug\521msvc20123.exe_manifest.rc
>     if not exist debug\521msvc20123.exe if exist
>   debug\521msvc20123.exe.embed.manifest del
>   debug\521msvc20123.exe.embed.manifest     if exist
>   debug\521msvc20123.exe.embed.manifest copy /Y
>   debug\521msvc20123.exe.embed.manifest
>   debug\521msvc20123.exe_manifest.bak
>           1 file(s) copied.     link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32'
>   name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0'
>   publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'
>   processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST
>   /MANIFESTFILE:debug\521msvc20123.exe.embed.manifest
>   /OUT:debug\521msvc20123.exe
>   @C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Temp\521msvc20123.exe.7128.2875.jom
>     if exist debug\521msvc20123.exe_manifest.bak fc /b
>   debug\521msvc20123.exe.embed.manifest
>   debug\521msvc20123.exe_manifest.bak >NUL || del
>   debug\521msvc20123.exe_manifest.bak   if not exist
>   debug\521msvc20123.exe_manifest.bak rc.exe
>   /fodebug\521msvc20123.exe_manifest.res
>   debug\521msvc20123.exe_manifest.rc    if not exist
>   debug\521msvc20123.exe_manifest.bak link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE
>   /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32'
>   name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0'
>   publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'
>   processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST
>   /MANIFESTFILE:debug\521msvc20123.exe.embed.manifest
>   /OUT:debug\521msvc20123.exe
>   @C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Temp\521msvc20123.exe.7128.2891.jom
>     if exist debug\521msvc20123.exe_manifest.bak del
>   debug\521msvc20123.exe_manifest.bak 22:21:32: The process
>   "C:\qtcreator-3.1.0\bin\jom.exe" exited normally. 22:21:32: Elapsed
>   time: 00:08.

What can be the problem?

[Qt QQmlApplicationEngine refuse to display qml code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584970/qt-qqmlapplicationengine-refuse-to-display-qml-code)
is not about the Rectangle element, its about the missing visible property in ApplicationWindow element.

Comment: Duplicate of [Qt QQmlApplicationEngine refuse to display qml code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584970/qt-qqmlapplicationengine-refuse-to-display-qml-code)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlapplicationengine.html#details),

> Unlike QQuickView, **QQmlApplicationEngine does not automatically create
>   a root window**. If you are using visual items from Qt Quick, you will
>   need to place them inside of a Window.

So you need to place your `Rectangle` inside a `Window`.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

Of course, you can alternatively use `QQuickView` instead of `QQmlApplicationEngine`. In this case, the code should be the following one:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView engine(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    engine.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: "red"
}
```